# assigning values to struct array problem!

Tags: c

The following code is shorten form, I have two structurs named struct INTERFACE and struct node.
For my purpose I have 2 nodes and first node have two interfaces and second node have three interfaces.

I have one config file from wher I need to read the information and store it in the above structures.

So in my main program while loop , I read the config file using strtok() fun, and store respectively.
In the if loop (if(strcmp((p,"IP_ADDR_ETH")==0), I compared the IP address token and retrive the ip address and store in the interfaces of each node. Why i am using switch case because if NODE-1 means first node, NODE-2 means second node.
Here I shown only for first node.

In the if loop I retrive the IP address of first node and store it in node structure's interface value.
by,

```
(node1[i].node_if[a].ip_addr)= p;
                                //strcpy((node1[i].node_if[a].ip_addr),p);
                        printf("Node[%d] interface-eth[%d] address=%s \n\n", i,a,(node1[i].node_if[a].ip_addr) );
```

Inside the while loop, for each node ,I can access the interface structure and get ipaddr value properly.
But out side the while loop, if I am printing the each nodes interface values, I am getting only the second node last interface value, I am not able to get each nodes interface ipaddress properly.

My part of the main code is as follows, sorry if the code length is more again, but I gave only nessary portion only,

```
/* Node information structure. */
typedef struct node {
    char name[20];
    char val[20];
    char OS[10];
    int vm_id;
    int num_if;
    //char *OS;
    if_val1 node_if[10];
    long int memsize;
}node1;

/* Interfaces definition structure. */
typedef struct INTERFACE {
    char *ip_addr;
    char *netmask;
    char *gateway;
} if_val1,if_val2;

I have the above two structure.


/* File pointer .*/
FILE *f;


int main()
{

    node1 nodeuse;
    node1 node1[20];
    //if_val1 if_val[10];   
    if_val1 zero_ifintf;

    //int a;
    f=fopen("test.config","r");
    if(!f)
    return 1;

    while(fgets( string, sizeof(string)-1, f) != NULL)
    {
        /* Break into tokens. */
        p = string;
        p = strtok( string, seps ); /* Find first token*/
        while( p != NULL )
        {
        if (strcmp(p,"NODE")==0)
            {

            a = atoi (strtok( NULL, seps )); /* Find next token*/
            switch (a)
                {
                case 1:
                {
                int i=0;
                if(strcmp(p,"IP_ADDR_ETH")==0)
                        {

                            printf("--------------hi1 \n");
                            int comp,a;
                            printf("------------hi2 \n");
                            a = atoi (strtok( NULL, seps )); /* Find next token*/

                            if(a < (node1[i].num_if))
                            {
                                printf("-------------hi3 \n");
                                p = strtok( NULL, seps ); /* Find next token*/
                                (node1[i].node_if[a].ip_addr)= p;
                                //strcpy((node1[i].node_if[a].ip_addr),p);
                        printf("Node[%d] interface-eth[%d] address=%s \n\n", i,a,(node1[i].node_if[a].ip_addr) );
                            }

                            printf("---------------------hi4 \n");
                        }
                    i++;
                }
                }}  //end of while loop

        //outside while loop printf 's  

            printf("NODE[%d] INTERFACE-ETH-[%d] ADDRESS: %s \n",1,0,(node1[0].node_if[0].ip_addr));
            printf("NODE[%d] INTERFACE-ETH-[%d] ADDRESS: %s \n",1,1,(node1[0].node_if[1].ip_addr));
            printf("NODE[%d] INTERFACE-ETH-[%d] ADDRESS: %s \n",2,0,(node1[1].node_if[0].ip_addr));
            printf("NODE[%d] INTERFACE-ETH-[%d] ADDRESS: %s \n",2,1,(node1[1].node_if[1].ip_addr));
            printf("NODE[%d] INTERFACE-ETH-[%d] ADDRESS: %s \n",2,2,(node1[1].node_if[2].ip_addr));
```

why the structure values not printed as expected.

also, I am trying to assign tokenized string value to other string using strcpy() function. But when compile segmentation fault came. Is it possible to declare char *string and assing value using strcpy()?.

my config file as follows,
[test.config]

```
TYPE VM vm1
TYPE PM pm1 
NODES 2
APS 2
TYPE wired
NODE-1 NUM_IF 2
NODE-1 IP_ADDR_ETH-0 10.114.12.1
NODE-1 IP_ADDR_ETH-1 10.114.12.2
NODE-1 VM_ID 1
NODE-1 MEM_SIZE 512
NODE-1 OS FEDORA

NODE-2 NUM_IF 3
NODE-2 IP_ADDR_ETH-0 10.114.14.1
NODE-2 IP_ADDR_ETH-1 10.114.14.2
NODE-2 IP_ADDR_ETH-2 10.114.14.3
NODE-2 VM_ID 2
NODE-2 MEM_SIZE 1GB
NODE-2 OS CENTOS
NODE-2 10.114.12.7
```

[/test.config]

Thank you,

Arun

Comment: Please spend some time and read the [*formatting help*](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Format your question properly so that others have a chance to answer you.

Answer (score 0):

```
strcmp(p,"IP_ADDR_ETH")
```

will never match because at this time p points to "NODE". Once you fixed that, it should work.